# Baked texture is tinted pink

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I followed this tutorial for baking the texture of barrel.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLEpjSFHl4o&t=355sa)

Now, the baked texture turned out pink.
Which doesn't happen in the tutorial video.

Did I miss something?
Thank you in advance.

[image]

[More images here on Imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLnm5.jpg)

Comment: Hi. Please add images using the built-in uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post You can [edit] your post using the link under it.

Answer (score 1):

Your current bake setup is set to Normal baking. I believe what you're attempting to do (if you're following that tutorial) is either Combined or Diffuse (colour) baking.

[image]